# how to add another phone field for confirmation in woocommerce checkout page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

[image]

Hi, I would like it to be like in the image and if the phone number don't match then it would not validate

really need help, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is my answer to adding custom field in the billing section

[image]

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'bbloomer_add_field_and_reorder_fields' );

function bbloomer_add_field_and_reorder_fields( $fields ) {

    if (!$_POST['shipping_method_tax_exempt']) {
        unset($fields['extra_fields']['claimant_name']);
        unset($fields['extra_fields']['description_illness']);
        unset($fields['extra_fields']['vat_confirm']);      
    }    

    // Add New Fields

    $fields['billing']['billing_phone_confirm'] = array(
    'label'     => __('Phone confirm', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'  => true,
    'class'     => array('form-row-last'),
    'clear'     => false
     );


    /*$fields['shipping']['shipping_houseno'] = array(
    'label'     => __('House Number', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder'   => _x('House Number', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'  => true,
    'class'     => array('form-row-last'),
    'clear'     => false
     );*/

    // Remove Address_2 Fields

    unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']);
    //unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_address_2']);

    // Make Address_1 Fields Half Width

    //$fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['class'] = array('form-row-first');
    //$fields['shipping']['shipping_address_1']['class'] = array('form-row-first');

    $fields['billing']['billing_country_field']['class'] = array('form-row-first');

    // Billing: Sort Fields

    $newfields['billing']['billing_first_name'] = $fields['billing']['billing_first_name'];
    $newfields['billing']['billing_last_name']  = $fields['billing']['billing_last_name'];
    $newfields['billing']['billing_company']    = $fields['billing']['billing_company'];
    $newfields['billing']['billing_email']      = $fields['billing']['billing_email'];
    $newfields['billing']['billing_phone']      = $fields['billing']['billing_phone'];
    $newfields['billing']['billing_phone_confirm']    = $fields['billing']['billing_phone_confirm'];
    $newfields['billing']['billing_country']    = $fields['billing']['billing_country'];
    $newfields['billing']['billing_address_1']  = $fields['billing']['billing_address_1'];  
    //$newfields['billing']['billing_address_2']  = $fields['billing']['billing_address_2'];
    $newfields['billing']['billing_city']       = $fields['billing']['billing_city'];
    $newfields['billing']['billing_postcode']   = $fields['billing']['billing_postcode'];
    $newfields['billing']['billing_state']      = $fields['billing']['billing_state'];

    // Shipping: Sort Fields

    $newfields['shipping']['shipping_first_name'] = $fields['shipping']['shipping_first_name'];
    $newfields['shipping']['shipping_last_name']  = $fields['shipping']['shipping_last_name'];
    $newfields['shipping']['shipping_company']    = $fields['shipping']['shipping_company'];
    $newfields['shipping']['shipping_country']    = $fields['shipping']['shipping_country'];
    $newfields['shipping']['shipping_address_1']  = $fields['shipping']['shipping_address_1'];  
    $newfields['shipping']['shipping_houseno']    = $fields['shipping']['shipping_houseno'];
    $newfields['shipping']['shipping_city']       = $fields['shipping']['shipping_city'];
    $newfields['shipping']['shipping_state']      = $fields['shipping']['shipping_state'];
    $newfields['shipping']['shipping_postcode']   = $fields['shipping']['shipping_postcode'];

    $checkout_fields = array_merge( $fields, $newfields);
    return $checkout_fields;
}
```

now the problem is the confirmation, it should not validate if it does not match

here is what I'm using now

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'wc_check_confirm_phone_matches_checkout', 10, 2 );

function wc_check_confirm_phone_matches_checkout( $posted ) {
    $checkout = WC()->checkout;

        if ( strcmp( $posted['billing_phone'], $posted['billing_phone_confirm_field'] ) !== 0 ) {
            wc_add_notice( __( 'Phone number do not match.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
        }

}
```

The problem here is that is always shows "Phone number do not match." even if it matches, need help on this

Answer (score 0):

/**

- Add the field to the checkout page

*/

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'some_custom_checkout_field' );

functionsome_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {

echo '

### ' . __('Heading') . '

';

woocommerce_form_field( 'some_field_name', array(

'type'         => 'text',

'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),

'label'         => __('Additional Field'),

'placeholder'   => __('Some hint'),

'required'     => true,

), $checkout->get_value( 'some_field_name' ));

echo '';

}

Comment: Hi, sorry but I need a phone number confirmation in the billing address section